# Overriding DSDT did it work?

Tags: acpi, bios, dmesg

I have compiled a kernel using a custom DSDT file. I just want to make sure the kernel is using it. When I run    `dmesg |grep DSDT`  I get this:

```
[    0.000000] ACPI: Override [DSDT-Notebook], this is unsafe: tainting kernel
[    0.000000] ACPI: DSDT @ 0x00000000baf87018 Table override, replaced with:
[    0.000000] ACPI: DSDT ffffffff81c647e0 1013B (v01 _ASUS_ Notebook 00000000 INTL 20111123)
[    0.430318] ACPI: EC: Look up EC in DSDT
```

Does this mean that it found it is using the custom DSDT or that it found it and replaced it with something not custom?

Comment: What makes you think that you need to overridfe the DSDT?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the DSDT is overridden. If you're confused by the "this is unsafe, tainting kernel" line, it means that you won't get support from the kernel developers should anything go wrong in your kernel.

Usually, you do not have to override the DSDT as errors in it should be corrected by the kernel (or a BIOS update if it really is wrong).